# How can I structure the date in this order Month day and year for this script

Tags: php

I have a script that converts a date and a time from a targeted time zone into another time zone. Everything works great, but I find the `dateTime()` structure to be very annoying by putting the year first and then the month and last the day.

For example:

```
<?php

$date = new DateTime('2011-6-30 4:52pm', new DateTimeZone('America/Phoenix'));

$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Asia/Baghdad'));

echo $date->format('n-j-Y g:i A');

?>
```

I was wondering if there are other methods that I can use to structure the date like this:

```
<?php

$date = new DateTime('6-30-2011 4:52pm', new DateTimeZone('America/Phoenix'));

$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Asia/Baghdad'));

echo $date->format('n-j-Y g:i A');

?>
```

The month first, the day second, and the year last. Do I have to use another method to create a structure like this? Or, if I don't have to change my method, then how can I adjust the code to make it work in that order?

I tried to change it into my desired order but it caused this error:

> *Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (6-30-2011 4:52pm) at position 0 (6): Unexpected character in C:\xampp\htdocs\xxx.php:3 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\xxx.php(3): DateTime->__construct('6-30-2011 4:52p...', Object(DateTimeZone)) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\xxx.php on line 3*

Answer (score 1):

The reason it defaults to that format is because dates like '3-5-2019' would be ambiguous:  is it March 5 or 3rd of May?

Nevertheless, what you are looking for is [createFromFormat()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d-Y h:ia', '6-30-2011 4:52pm',new DateTimeZone( 'America/Phoenix'));

$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Asia/Baghdad'));

echo $date->format('n-j-Y g:i A');
```

For all that work, I'd certainly put it in a function:

```
function convertCSTtoAST(String $cst) 
{
  $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d-Y h:ia', $cst, new DateTimeZone( 'America/Phoenix'));
  $date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Asia/Baghdad'));
  return $date->format('n-j-Y g:i A');
}
```

Error handling is left to you :)

Comment: Can you give an example with my code? So I can better understand how this can be done if that's possible?

Comment: Thanks for the example but it gave me this error 
Warning: DateTime::createFromFormat() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given in C:\xampp\htdocs\xxx.php on line 3

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function setTimezone() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\xxx.php:5 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\xxx.php on line 5

Comment: Oh, drat.  I don't have a console to work on.  It needs to be a string representation of the time you're wanting converted.

Comment: Thanks for your response I got you cover. I use this as a console http://www.writephponline.com/       I'm getting errors trying to do this on my own :(

Comment: I did something like that earlier as well your updated example is giving this error now  Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 3 passed to DateTime::createFromFormat() must be an instance of DateTimeZone or null, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\xxx.php:3 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\xxx.php(3): DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d-Y h:ia', '6-30-2011 4:52p...', 'America/Phoenix') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\xxx.php on line 3

Comment: Is the time zone important to the input? You’re immediately changing it.  Something doesn’t seem quite right about that. But then again it’s late here and I’ve run out of brain cells...

Comment: @DannyLee Like I said, I just needed to RTM.  works now.

Answer (score 0):

You can always write your own function (or a class):

```
<?php

$date = dateTime(6, 30, 2011, '4:52pm', 'America/Phoenix');

$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Asia/Baghdad'));

echo $date->format('n-j-Y g:i A');


function dateTime($mon, $day, $year, $time, $zone){
  return new DateTime("$year-$mon-$day $time", new DateTimeZone($zone));
}

?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but I got this error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ',' or ')' in C:\xampp\htdocs\xxx.php on line 11 and how can I avoid putting the date like this 6, 30, 2011 and avoid using a function and a return ? I simply just want to put the date like this 6-30-2011

Comment: @DannyLee I edited the return in dateTime, so it should work for you now. Yong was missing a closing parenthesis

Comment: @DannyLee you need to see [Tim's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56553641/how-can-i-structure-the-date-in-this-order-month-day-and-year-for-this-script/#56553854).

Comment: And his example has errors Yong Quan but thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Lol Danny Lee We on the wrong computers again ha ha ha I told you to get unique Lap top computers

Comment: Here it goes again @fsofb ha ha ha I see you ha ha

Comment: Duh we are sitting next to each other aha ha sorry @YongQuan for the mixed up this tends to happen some times lol